# No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting. [predictionio]

Tags: predictionio

[Please click this link to see the exact log i am seeing after running pio build. It fails as it can't find engine. Help would be much appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GPMG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet the same problem, because I specified scala.version=2.11.8 when I build PredictionIO but the engine template I used  was build with scala 2.10.

so I edit **build.sbt** file under engine's folder, and add `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`, re-run the build command(`pio build --verbose`), then everything build finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of scala you are using in the engine's build.sbt version and make sure you use that version when you build from source like this:

`./make-distribution.sh -Dscala.version=<PUT CORRECT SCALA VERSION HERE> -Dspark.version=2.1.0 -Delasticsearch.version=2.3.3`