# building MySimilarProduct engine in PIO

Tags: predictionio

when i'am building engine with cmd:   **pio build --verbose**
                                                                             i'am getting error

```
Using existing engine manifest JSON at /MySimilarProduct/MyProduct/manifest.json
[INFO] [Console$] Using command '/PredictionIO-0.10.0-incubating/sbt/sbt' at the current working directory to build.
[INFO] [Console$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.
[INFO] [Console$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.10.0-incubating.jar is absent.
[INFO] [Console$] Going to run: /PredictionIO-0.10.0-incubating/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Loading project definition from /MySimilarProduct/MyProduct/project
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Set current project to template-scala-parallel-similarproduct (in build file:/MySimilarProduct/MyProduct/)
[INFO] [Console$] [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 5, 2018 11:35:46 AM
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Including from cache: scala-library-2.11.8.jar
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Merging files...
[INFO] [Console$] [warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[INFO] [Console$] [warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Assembly up to date: /MySimilarProduct/MyProduct/target/scala-2.11/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar
[INFO] [Console$] [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 5, 2018 11:35:47 AM
[INFO] [Console$] Build finished successfully.
[INFO] [Console$] Looking for an engine...
[ERROR] [Console$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting.
```

I tried this link
 **[No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting. [predictionio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622587/no-engine-found-your-build-might-have-failed-aborting-predictionio)** but my default scala version is 2.11.8 and build.sbt is

```
name := "template-scala-parallel-similarproduct"

parallelExecution in Test := false
test in assembly := {}

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.predictionio" %% "apache-predictionio-core" % "0.12.0-incubating" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"        %% "spark-mllib"              % "2.1.1" % "provided",
  "org.scalatest"           %% "scalatest"                % "3.0.4" % "test")
```

Any help would be appreciated. thankyou in advance

Comment: Were able to resolve this? I am facing similar issues!

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the `$PIO_HOME`?

Before running `pio build`, you should change to the engine's directory (where engine.json exists).

Or you can use `pio build -v engine.json`.